# Search terms within google referring url missing

Tags: web-services

I have a program that gathers information from referring urls.  Today i noticed that if you are logged in to google and perform a search, the "q=" is empty when it comes through.

Example:

```
logged in:  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&ved=0CIQBEBYwATgK

not logged in:  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=live%20chat&source=web&ved=0CFkQFjABOAo
```

Is there a setting in the persons google account that disables this, or a google service that i can query for the keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely what you are looking for, though you may have found the answer already. Check the [Google Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html)